# Attribute type not allowed on element video at this point. how to fix this error?

Tags: html, validation, audio, video, markup

I'm getting an error when validating audio & video in my HTML markup using the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

```
      Validation Output: 1 Error

        Error Line 28, Column 96: Attribute type not allowed on element video at this                   point.
   …ls="controls"  poster="Images/egg.jpg" src="Misc/chicken.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       Attributes for element video:

     Global attributes
       src
       crossorigin
       poster
       preload
       autoplay
       mediagroup
       loop
       muted
       controls
       width
       height
```

how do i fix this foraudio & video if i use mp3 & mp4 files??

Comment: does anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: cant seem to know why i cant use mpeg or mp4 type

Answer (score 1):

The [`video` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element) can’t have a `type` attribute.

Maybe you want to use the [`source` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/embedded-content-0.html#the-source-element) as child of `video`?